# showing splash screen on cold start of app links

Tags: xamarin.android, android-app-links

I'm adding app linking to my android app and I'm noticing on cold starts there's this long period of a white screen, which the user could interpret it as the app is not responding.

I have a splash screen for normal operation of the app on the main activity using a special theme, but it looks like app linking bypasses that activity so is there a way to show a splash screen on the other screens when the app is accessed by a link action?

EDIT:
quick summary, the splash screen appears during the normal use of the app but when a link triggers the app to open, it's not.

Comment: What does this `show a splash screen on the other screens when the app is accessed by a link action` mean?  Does the splash screen not show?

Comment: no, so if I open the app up normally I see the splash screen. If the app opens up from a user clicking on a link in an email I get a white screen instead of the splash screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution for myself.

I simplified the intent filters to all call from the main activity that has the splash screen so it will appear now on cold starts.

this cleaned up a few other issues so it's a win overall for me.